# Cannot connect to mysql datavbase ERROR Access denied for user... (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, remote-access, remote-server

Running a php script or trying to connect via terminal (locally) I get the same error

> Access denied for user... (using password: YES)

mysql -u **username** -p'password' -h **ip** **db_name**

It passes to the server but get's blocked because of password although correct value was provided.

I've tried several fixes associated to this scenario but to no avail.

When a tried to execute some queries which could provide extra info for the fix, I get

> 1142 - SELECT command denied to user ... for table 'user'

I've assigned username, password and all privileges in cPanel MySql databases section (for the database) but am unable to connect using the created user as if a root user is blocking access to the database.

Am on GoDaddy host.

These are the only actions that I can preform on my database

[image]

Comment: In mysql, a user is also associated to a hostname. Have you enabled this user for the host you are connecting from?

Comment: @ADyson I'll check this option right away, although I remember that I haven't encountered such thing, but let me check

Comment: @ADyson no, nothing so far, I don't see the section where I could do this.

Comment: Normally the user is configured as (for example) `user@localhost` specifying a specific host, or sometimes  `user@%` with the percent sign being a wildcard indicating any host. The user can only log in from the hosts specified. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: P.s. if you are in a hosted account it may be that the hosting control panel hides this from you and only allows users to connect from within the hosting environment